# Display 2 components on 2 screens and synchronizing them

Tags: javascript, angular, display

I wish to implement an application which can run on 2 screens.When I select something on one screen, the details appear in the second screen.

I could use local storage, but i feel that I might have different type of data to be shared between the screens.

```
              DUAL DISPLAY
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use postMessage. Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage
On one window you just `targetWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer]);`
And on second you set up `window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);`